# Do not have "Go to admin" menu when creating docusign account using REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign REST API (DocuSign C# Client) to create a DocuSign account for our clients. An account is created successfully, but when the user login that account on DocuSign Web (New UI) then they do not get "Go to Admin" menu in admin preferences. Is there any settings that we need to apply while creating DocuSign account. We are using [DocuSign C# Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) to create an account and applying only email and user name.

Also, we want to update some DocuSign account settings using REST API. But some parameters are not getting updated. When I checked the API log and found that parameter which we want to modify its read only. Below what i found from API log.

"allowEnvelopeCorrect":"false","allowEnvelopeCorrectMetadata":{"rights":"read_only","uiHint":"available"}

Comment: Hi Jigar, there's actually a bug in the platform currently that will be fixed soon - the bug is that for single user accounts the Go To Admin link in the menu drop menu is not available. I believe this might be causing your issue.  Starting tomorrow you should be able to access the Admin menu directly through - https://admin.docusign.com/auth - and I think next week the actual menu item should be enabled and bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the update Ergin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a bug in the platform currently that will be fixed soon - the bug is that for single user accounts the Go To Admin link in the menu drop menu is not available. I believe this might be causing your issue. Starting tomorrow you should be able to access the Admin menu directly through - admin.docusign.com/auth - and I think next week the actual menu item should be enabled and bug fixed.
-- By Ergin

It has been fixed Now.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below on another thread, I would try to explicitly call `canManageAccount` and see if the permission gets set. It may still need to be done in SOAP.

[Fail to update user's "Manage Account" permission through "Modify User Account Settings" API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469472/fail-to-update-users-manage-account-permission-through-modify-user-account-s/32472027#32472027)

Are you creating new accounts through the API or just adding new users to an account?

Comment: I am creating new account through the API

Comment: And also while creating account I have set canManageAccount to true but still its not working.

Comment: with SOAP or REST?

Comment: With REST.. we are using [C# REST Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)