# Automating adding/removing administrators through DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently in the process of syncing DocuSign user groups and signing groups, using Active Directory as the authoritative source. I'm dealing with a couple of issues during this process:

1 - When a new user is created, I'd like to give them the "DocuSign Viewer" permission set, and then assign any other access through the permissions on a user group. I've looked through all of the DocuSign API recipes, but I don't see where you can do that through the API. The closest I see is adding them to a group, and then setting the permissions on the group. Since the group permission policies are preset, that wouldn't help.

2 - When adding a new user to the Administrator DocuSign group, the user is created in DocuSign, but they aren't added to the group. I'm doing both with one API call.  This is a sample of the body of the call to "/v2/accounts/{AccountId}/users":

```
{    
    "newUsers": [
    {
        "email":"email address",
        "firstName": "First",
        "lastName": "Last",
        "userName": "First Last",
        "groupList": [
        {
            "groupId": "groupId",               
            "users": [
                {
                    "email": "email address",
                    "userName": "First Last"                    
                }
                     ]
        }
    ],
    "isAdmin": "true",
    "userType": "companyuser"           
    }
    ]
}
```

I use this same API call for a group that we created and it works as expected. I Also tried creating the user and adding them to the Administrator group using separate API calls.

This works, but since they aren't assigned to a permissions set, deleting the user from the group doesn't work properly. They are removed from the Administrator group, but "Account Admin" remains populated with "Yes", which still gives them administrator abilities.

If I were able to set their permission to "DocuSign Viewer" when creating their account, that would solve this issue. I've tried altering the "isAdmin" property through the API, but it doesn't remove the YES, or make any difference in the code I pasted above.

Does anyone have some experience with altering Administrator accounts through the API or have other best practices? Our API isn't certified yet, so this is all taking place in demo. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check out my comment in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469472/fail-to-update-users-manage-account-permission-through-modify-user-account-s/32472027#32472027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that allows us to add "DocuSign Viewer" to an account as it's being created through the API. I noticed that the "Everyone" user group didn't have a permissions profile set for it, so I added "DocuSign Viewer". Since that's a default group for everyone, there's no group management involved with giving users the desired viewer abilities.  Now, when they are removed from a group with heightened permissions, they fall back to view access.

The administrator group still throws a couple of wrenches at us, but we've learned how to deal with it.

Since you can't add permissions to groups in NDSE, I'm not sure if this solution will be permanent or just a band-aid.